# how to assign a value to a string array?

Tags: c, string

for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char substr[10][20];

int main() {
    substr[0] = "abc";

    printf("%d", substr[0]);
}
```

of course above is wrong? how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign strings like that in C. Instead, use `strcpy(substr[0], "abc")`. Also, use `%s` not `%d` in your `printf`

Answer (score 3):

I hate giving 'full' answers to homework questions, but the only way to answer your question is to show you the answer to your problem, because it is so basic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 20

char substr[10][MAXLEN];

int main(void) {
        strncpy(substr[0], "abc", MAXLEN);
        puts(substr[0]);
        return 0;
}
```

Your code (as is) has several faults:

- You are treating `substr[0]` as a string literal. You can't do that.
- You were using printf formatters incorrectly. `%s` is for strings
- You don't *need* to bother `printf()` to print a string
- You should (in real code) watch out for buffer overflows, hence `strncpy()`
- If `main()` doesn't want / need `argc` and `argv`, its arguments should be `void`
- `main()` should return a value, as its return type is `int`
- You aren't using anything out of `<stdlib.h>`, why include it?

I suggest researching string literals, the functions available in `<string.h>` as well as format specifiers.

Also note, I am ***not checking the return of strncpy()***, which is something you should be doing. That is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
void main(void)
{
    char* string[10];
    string[0] = "Hello";
}
```

Otherwise I think ya need to copy it by hand or use strcpy or the like to move it from one block of memory to another.